# Android mail client using Exchange Web Services?

Tags: email, exchange

I'm looking for an Android e-mail client that connects to a hosted Exchange 2010 server via [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) (EWS). I know there are several mail apps (including the stock mail client) that can work with Exchange through ActiveSync and/or WebDAV, but my server supports neither of these.

Comment: can you please tell me how you fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've found:

- [AquaMail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kman.AquaMail)

  - "Support for standard Internet email protocols: IMAP, POP3, SMTP; Exchange: **EWS**" ([reference](http://www1.mobisystems.com/aqua-mail/))
- [Blue Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.bluemail.mail)

  - "Support for … Exchange (ActiveSync, **EWS**, 365)"
  - cloud-involved
- [Email TypeApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trtf.blue)

  - "Supporting … all Exchange protocols including **Exchange Web Services (EWS)**"
  - probably cloud-involved
- [MailCal for Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devsite.mailcal)

  - "email and calendar client that uses **EWS**/OWA/Webmail"
- [MailDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maildroid)

  - various forum postings discuss EWS support
- [MobiMail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.Appstervan.MobiMail)

  - "**Exchange Web Services (EWS)** is required on the Exchange server"
- [Newton Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmagic.mail)

  - "Supports Calendar for Gmail, Google Apps, and Exchange (**EWS**)"
  - cloud-involved
- [Stack Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.squash.mail), a.k.a. Ginger Mail, a.k.a. Squash Mail

  - "Please make sure that **EWS (Exchange Web Services)** is enabled on your Exchange server"
  - [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4e25bm/looks_like_google_is_refunding_purchases_of_stack/) says Google was refunding purchases

Honorable mention:

- AOL Alto - [discontinued November 9, 2017](https://www.androidauthority.com/aol-alto-email-app-discontinued-809867/)

Answer (score 0):

[JWebServices for Exchange](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices) is Java API for Microsoft Exchange 2007/2010/2013 and Office 365. The API offers complete Exchange Web Services functionality including the ability to create/update/move/copy items and folders, search items and folders, send messages, send meetings requests and more. Supports JDK 1.5+ and Android 1.6+.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft's EWS API which is Open Source for Android by doing the following steps:

1. download the source code available in the URL: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi
   **EWSJavaAPI_1.1.5.zip**
2. Make the changes to above API to work for JDK 1.4 in Eclipse like remove override annotations, etc.
3. Download source code of javax.* package available in below URL
   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsr17310srcjar.htm 
   **jsr173_1.0_src.jar.zip**
4. Download source code of stax API available in below URL,
   http://dist.codehaus.org/stax/distributions
   **stax-src-1.2.0.zip**
5. Keep all the sources under the single Java project in Eclipse
6. Open the project explorer and select the package which are starts with "**javax**" and rename to your company name (e.g., **com**). *Note:* Eclipse will ask for all the naming contexts will change then click OK.
7. Export all the Java sources to one single jar file.
8. Then You good to go to use the jar in Android application with out any problems.

I used the same way explained above and it worked in Android application 100% perfectly.

Comment: This may be viable for someone who is familiar with programming, but isn't going to be helpful for most users.

Comment: it is not working for me, are these steps complete ? please help